# How to tweet from a local webpage

Tags: javascript, authentication, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I made a webpage that I open in my browser that uses Javascript to help me construct what I want to send on twitter. Then I have to copy and paste the text into a Twitter client in order to actually send it.

I would like to just have a button that I press on my page that will send the tweet instead of doing this. Is it possible? I've been looking at [jsOAuth](https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth) and it seems I need things like a consumer key and secret? I don't have those things. This isn't a public app, it's just something I'm making for my own personal use.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a regular tweet button.  You can provide the text that you want to tweet about. Normally you would think this is for public use, but I've found it very useful for an admin section.  Here is the link to the twitter dev page:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button

Comment: That just seems to be for tweeting a link.

Comment: you can add a data-text attribute to the tag that provides the text.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK OAuth requires a site to redirect to, also for cookie purposes.
There is something called OAuth for devices that let's you authenticate the application instead of the browser/client. Facebook supports it, Iam not sure if twitter does it too.
hth